# Initialize Component Error C#

Tags: c#, initializecomponent

So I was all done with my program and tried to edit a few small things at the top, and started getting errors and can't change them back.  Here is the code:

```
namespace FinalProject
{
    public partial class Form : Form
    {
        public Form();
        {
           InitializeComponent();

        }
    }
}
```

I changed the Form: Form part and then it made the `InitializeComponent();` into an error.  Tried to change it back and its still showing the error.  Undo is not an option and I'm sure it's an easy fix.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your question. Try to clarify, explain what is expected, what is actual, what you did, and exact error messages if any.

Comment: `public Form();` ?? is it a typo ? this should be `public Form()` I guess

Comment: Can you tell the complete error? and have a look inside InitializeComponent may be there is still something wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Remove the semicolon at the end of the first line of the constructor.
2. Change your class name to something other than "Form".

Comment: The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context.  <---That's my error.

Comment: Change also the class name in the designer.cs file

Answer (score 3):

A Class named Form cannot inherit another class also named Form. You have to give it a different name.

Comment: InitializeComponent(); Became underlined, and all the void parts of my code are red underlined, and my array names and streamreaders are all underlined.